# how to validate checkbox number in Yii

Tags: validation, checkbox, yii

My page has many checkbox, varies from 5 to 100, I need to verify the checked number. The minimal number is 2, max is 8. I went through yii documents, and not found such a validation method. How can I achieve this in an elegant way?

In addition, I want to save the checkbox value in session while user manipulating it , how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

By using **range** validation you can achieve this functionality.

Rule will come something like bellow. Just modify this according to your program

```
    public function rules()
    {       
        return array(
                array('your_attribute', 'required'),                    
                array('your_attribute', 'in','range'=>range(2,8),'message'=>'Range should be in 400 to 690'),           
        );
    }
```

I got some syntax here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25286-yii-numbers-range-validator/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a little difference to my situation. I need to limit the total selected checkbox number while the answer is validating a number. Any way, I will have a try.

Comment: I used javascript to achieve this, checking the checkbox number when it changes.